# Udacity: Assignment 3: ValueError: bad input shape (1000, 10)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am working on [Assignment 3: Regularization](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud730/l-6379031992/m-6598158989). After taking a look into that [Github](https://github.com/shawpan/deep_learning_assignments/blob/master/3_regularization.ipynb), I tried to solve the assignment one my own, but I am getting a runtime error. Note that I have picked a smaller size of the dataset, than the link.

This is the situation:

```
print('Training set', train_dataset.shape, train_labels.shape)
print('Validation set', valid_dataset.shape, valid_labels.shape)
print('Test set', test_dataset.shape, test_labels.shape)
#Training set (20000, 784) (20000, 10)
#Validation set (1000, 784) (1000, 10)
#Test set (1000, 784) (1000, 10)
```

and here is the problem:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

original_train_labels = train_labels

logit_clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2')
logit_clf.fit(train_dataset[:1000,:], original_train_labels[:1000])
```

which when run, gives:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-4888dc0bbc75> in <module>()
      4 
      5 logit_clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2')
----> 6 logit_clf.fit(train_dataset[:1000,:], original_train_labels[:1000])
      7 predicted = logit_clf.predict(test_dataset)
      8 print('accuracy', accuracy((np.arange(num_labels) == predicted[:,None]).astype(np.float32), test_labels), '%')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1140 
   1141         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=np.float64, 
-> 1142                          order="C")
   1143         check_classification_targets(y)
   1144         self.classes_ = np.unique(y)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    513                         dtype=None)
    514     else:
--> 515         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    516         _assert_all_finite(y)
    517     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.pyc in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    549         return np.ravel(y)
    550 
--> 551     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
    552 
    553 

ValueError: bad input shape (1000, 10)
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306390/sklearn-classifier-get-valueerror-bad-input-shape

Comment: Hmm thanks @MosesKoledoye, but I fail to see exactly how should I solve my issue with that link (forgive my ignorance). Can you help? :)

Comment: The shape of your output is probably inappropriate. Can you print `original_train_labels.shape`?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye shouldn't that be (20000, 10)? Since `original_train_labels = train_labels`. I will check now. Yes, confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use one-hot encoding for train_labels. Meaning it has shape like [1000. 10], 1000 of samples and each has 10 'columns' with 1 indicating which class we are talking about. It is required for neural networks, but Logistics Regression from sklearn [requires](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit) it to be of shape [1000, 1], meaning that it should be just a vector of 1000 rows and in each row you should have an int which indicates target class. Convert one-hot encoding to integers with argmax function and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

[Maxim Haytovich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3633250/maxim-haytovich) is right, the shape of your train_labels have changed, you should keep a copy of your train labels before reformatting it to `(20000, 10)`. Initially `train_labels` has a shape of `(20000,)` which is a vector with class label values such as `[1 2 4 3 ..]`. Logistic Regression requires these class labels.

When you reformat with `train_dataset, train_labels = reformat(train_dataset, train_labels)` the train_labels become `(20000,10)` where previous `[1 2 4 3 ...]` becomes `[[1 0 0 0 0 ...], [0 1 0 0 ...], [0 0 0 1 0 ...], ...]` which is needed for neural network but will not work with Logistic Regression.

Then you assigned `original_train_labels = train_labels` that means original_train_labels has the same shape of `(20000, 10)`. So you will get Value Error for wrong shape of class labels. You need to perform the step `original_train_labels = train_labels` before `train_dataset, train_labels = reformat(train_dataset, train_labels)`. Check the order of steps below and correct your code accordingly [gsamaras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411320/gsamaras)

```
original_train_labels = train_labels
...
...
train_dataset, train_labels = reformat(train_dataset, train_labels)
...
...
logit_clf.fit(train_dataset[:1000,:], original_train_labels[:1000])
```